# Retrieving data from javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

The image below is a screenshot of 2 objects in an array.

How can I retrieve the dates and the string "" inside this array? Please consider if there is more than 1 object in the array.

I've created this function thus far:

```
function printData(data) {
  $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    //console.log(item);

    $.each(item, function(j, c) {
        //console.log(c); 

        $.each(c, function(k, l){
            //console.log(l.v);
        });
    });
  });

  //console.log(data.c.v);
  console.dir(data);
}
```

Can you tweak this function to get what I want.

[image: dump of object in chrome]

Edit:

The object:

```
data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'start');
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'end');
    data.addColumn('string', 'content');
```

A listener lets users to add events to the timeline, and I add the data to the timeline as follows:

```
var options = {
    "width":  "100%",
    "height": "300px",
    "editable": true,
    "style": "box"
};

 timeline.draw(data, options);
```

Here is the delete function (may help to distinguish selections of the object):

```
function doDelete() { /*** Delete the currently selected event */
    // retrieve the selected row
    var sel = timeline.getSelection();
    if (sel.length) {
        if (sel[0].row != undefined) {
            var row = sel[0].row;
        }
    }

    if (row != undefined) {
        timeline.deleteItem(row);
    } else {
        alert("First select an event, then press remove again");
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
```

**outputs:**

```
{
    "cols": [
        {
            "id": "",
            "label": "start",
            "pattern": "",
            "type": "datetime"
        },
        {
            "id": "",
            "label": "end",
            "pattern": "",
            "type": "datetime"
        },
        {
            "id": "",
            "label": "content",
            "pattern": "",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "c": [
                {
                    "v": "Date(2014, 3, 24)",
                    "f": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "Date(2014, 4, 1)",
                    "f": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "Subgoal A",
                    "f": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "c": [
                {
                    "v": "Date(2014, 4, 1)",
                    "f": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "Date(2014, 4, 8)",
                    "f": null
                },
                {
                    "v": "Subgoal B",
                    "f": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "p": null
}
```

Comment: Can you supply the actual object instead of the image of the object?

Comment: Hard to understand structure of your js object in the screenshot, Would be nice if you could post your json.

Comment: Hi, this is the API, just cant seem to find a GET ALL ITEMS() method. http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/timeline/doc/jsdoc/symbols/links.Timeline.html

Comment: @Chris: Your link doesn't really help. Can you include in your question the actual object you have and the object you want to generate from it. This ought to be pretty easy to do.

Comment: @MattBurland see edit, please let me know if that is enough insight for you.

Comment: Is there an error you get? Where is the empty string `""` inside that object, I can't spot any?

Comment: @Chris console `JSON.stringify(data)` and post us the structure of your `object`

Comment: @Bergi "Subgoal A" is the string, I used "" because it could represent any string, sorry for not making it clear

Comment: @Navin adding stringify to edit now, please take a look

Comment: This is still not working guys/gals, I keep getting the following error, as if the object has no length: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have 4 levels actually, and have only shown the `.rows` array of your `data` object in the screenshot. However, you should not just wrap another loop around it, but explicitly access that property - just as you have done with `.v` in the end. Also, the `.c` property should similarily be accessed explicitly instead of just being enumerated.

```
function printData(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // assuming this is the shown output
    $.each(data.rows, function(i, row) {    
        $.each(row.c, function(j, item) {
            console.log(item.v);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I didnt know the data was in a raw format, you have to parse the data object with JSON, thanks for taking the time to finding a solution! Thanks a billion. Reputation++;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you:

```
$(arr).each(function (index) {

    $(arr[index]).each(function (index1) {

        $(arr[index][index1]).each(function (index2) {

            alert(arr[index][index1][index2]);

        });

    });

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qhaLa/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
//obj - your object
$.each(obj.rows, function(i,rows){


$.each(rows, function(j, c){

    $.each(c, function(k, data){
        console.log("f: " + data.f + "v: " + data.v);
    });
});

});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5e9dE/)

Comment: That seems to work in the JSFiddle, but I can't get it to work within my code. I thought the variable data would be the object in question. I'm getting a "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error when running what you've put on the data object

Comment: @Chris Looks like the object shown in screenshot starts from only `rows` but the full object you provided starts from `cols`. In which format you're passing `data` to your `printData()` ?